# Getting Syntax Error in Python, but have correct number of tabs and followed syntax

Tags: python, whitespace, python-2.4

In some code I just added to a larger python file that already uses the syntax of Tabs instead of spaces (which I know is not recommended), I'm getting a syntax error in the code below. I'm using vim/python2.4, and turned on `:set list` to see whitespace characters. It doesn't look like I'm violating any indentation rules, and I'm following what exception should look like according to the documentation/other parts of the code which are working properly.

```
def writeXmlFile(self, testFilekey):

    #dictionary for xml values
    xml_d={}
    try:
        xml_d['test_r']=self.test_results
    except: TypeError
        xml_d['test_r']=-1     <-Syntax error at the first non-whitespace (x of xml_d)
    print "test_results"
    print xml_d['test_r']
```

Does this have to do with whitespace, or is there something else that I'm overlooking completely here?

Comment: please reformat the source code. trouble shooting a white space related issue with not proper formatting is very hard.

Answer (score 2):

Posting code like this is not helpful; it's very hard to see the actual text.

The problem is not with indentation, but with syntax, like the error says. The colon goes after the exception class, not before:

```
except TypeError:
```

All indented blocks in Python are introduced with a colon on the end of the previous line.

Comment: Well, that's what the OP should have done, but `except: TypeError` is valid syntactically, so by itself that wouldn't have caused a SyntaxError.  It would have caused an IndentationError on the following line.

Comment: Thank you. I deliberately posted it like so it would be clear that I used tabs instead of spaces/mix of the two.